# How to create a makefile using subdirectories for source and binary files

Tags: unix, makefile, directory, fortran, gfortran

I am trying to create a makefile in a parent directory with source files (src) and binary files (bin) in subdirectories.

Now I get the error:

> Makefile:27: warning: overriding recipe for target `bin'
>
> Makefile:24: warning: ignoring old recipe for target `bin'
>
> Makefile:26: *** mixed implicit and normal rules.  Stop.

I am a beginner with makefiles, so let me try to walk you through the file as I understand it:

First, compiler options are given using flags. Also, each subdirectory is given a flag.
Next, the files to be linked are defined.
pp is defined as the default procedure when calling 'make'.
$(BINDIR) is asigned a specific command (opening the subfolder 'bin').
Binary files are created in subfolder 'bin' using source files from 'src'.
Finally, some rules for removing all created files are given.

Am I missing something?

```
# Compiler Options
FC          = f95
FFLAGS      = -O3 -w
LDFLAGS     = -lfftw3
SRCDIR      = src
BINDIR      = bin 

# Object files
OBJS        =   $(BINDIR)/modules.o $(BINDIR)/subroutines.o\
                $(BINDIR)/adiabatic.o   $(BINDIR)/prop.o\
                $(BINDIR)/setpot.o      $(BINDIR)/prep_prop.o\
                $(BINDIR)/rk4.o     $(BINDIR)/main.o

# Build rules
default:    pp

pp:     $(OBJS)                     
    $(FC) *.o $(FFLAGS) $(LDFLAGS) -o pp

$(BINDIR):
    mkdir -p $(BINDIR)

$(BINDIR)/%.o: $(SRCDIR)/%.f90 | $(BINDIR)
    $(FC) $(FFLAGS) -c $^ -o $@ -J$(BINDIR)

# Clean rules       
clean:
    rm -f *.o 
    rm -f *.mod 
    rm -f pp
```

Comment: You have a space after `bin` in `BINDIR      = bin ` so your pattern rule ends up looking like `bin /%.o`, hence the override and mixed rule messages.

Comment: Wow... you are right :( Thank you so much!